# Heroku cleardb connection default addr for network unknown

Tags: mysql, heroku, go, cleardb

I have created a free instance of Heroku cleardb instance for my app. I set the database URL as:

```
heroku config:set DATABASE_URL='mysql://user:pass@us-cdbr-iron-east-03.cleardb.net/heroku_database?reconnect=true'
```

I'm trying to connect using a `Go` app. But when I try to access my application, it gives the following mysql error:

```
default addr for network 'us-cdbr-iron-east-03.cleardb.net' unknown
```

I tried to set the database url with protocol and port as well:

```
heroku config:set DATABASE_URL='mysql://user:pass@tcp(us-cdbr-iron-east-03.cleardb.net:3306)/heroku__database?reconnect=true'
```

This changes the errror to:

```
Access denied for user
```

which i'm guessing is because direct access to port is disallowed. Does anybody know what is the issue here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a `Go` specific problem. Three changes are required:

1. `Go`'s `sql.Open` already takes scheme as its first parameter so it needs to be stripped off of `DATABASE_URL`.
2. Connection string shouldn't have any query parameters (remove `?reconnect=true`).
3. Protocol (tcp) and port (3306 for MySQL) number *are* required.

Thus final database URL would be:

```
DATABASE_URL='user:pass@tcp(us-cdbr-iron-east-03.cleardb.net:3306)/your_heroku_database'
```